# Is the Bluemix graph database service running Titan under the hood?

Tags: ibm-cloud, titan

Is the [Bluemix graph database service](https://graph-data-store-docs.ng.bluemix.net/) running a regular version of Titan under the hood? won't it be phased out given the [TitanDB acquisition](http://www.datastax.com/2015/02/datastax-acquires-aurelius-the-experts-behind-titandb), and *how can it claim tinkerpop version 3 at a time when the open-sourced version of Titan is still at tinkerpop version 2?*

Answer (score 4):

Titan has continued development after the DataStax acquisition of Aurelius. Titan's lead developer Matthias Broecheler posted on the Titan mailing list in February 2015 after the acquisition announcement that Titan would continue on and have an open source release based on TinkerPop3. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/WTNYYpUyrvw/pZh02Q2LlpsJ

Matthias Broecheler will be presenting at the DataStax Cassandra Summit on the Titan 1.0 release. http://cassandrasummit-datastax.com/agenda/titan-1-0-scalable-real-time-and-analytic-graph-queries/

DataStax has a strong reputation for supporting open source technology, as evidenced by their continued support of the Apache Cassandra project.

Comment: still wonder how a service can claim tinkerpop3 and titan at the same time, unless there's a titan branch/fork out there that supports it

Comment: Titan development is occurring on the titan09 branch in GitHub https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/commits/titan09

Comment: Titan 1.0 is now available. http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/ and source code here on the titan10 branch https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/

Comment: tinkerpop 3 baked into it? I guess it would be written explicitly somewhere if it were

Comment: See the Titan Version Compatibility matrix in the official documentation http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/version-compat.html

Titan 1.0 uses TinkerPop 3.0.1 https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/titan10/pom.xml#L62

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not really about a coding issue. The linked document about the [Bluemix graph database service](https://graph-data-store-docs.ng.bluemix.net/#undefined) explicitly states that it is based on [Apache TinkerPop](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/). The Titan Database is also based on Apache TinkerPop according to the Apache TinkerPop website.

Comment: as is, your answer suggests a total lack of understanding of what tinkerpop is and what it is not.